# How to search and replace all instances of a string within a database?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, replace

I have a string that is contained inside of a wordpress install (the name of a server) thousands of times, across multiple columns, records and tables.

I'd like to update it with the location of another server - we are moving the content over.

So the source would be something like http://my-server1/some/link/to/something, and I'd want to replace it with http://my-other-server/some/link/to/something. I'm essentially looking to repeat this process for every instance of http://my-server1.

Is there an easy way to do this in MySQL? A tool?
Or do I sadly have to update every record problematically?

Thank you,

Comment: having these kind of data (the data should be at least absoute paths) in a database is a pretty bad idea since you need to change it when you move. Why do you have the site's URL in a Wordpress install anyway? There should be only the one, global site pref.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A crude (but effective) way of doing it would be to dump the schema into a file, carefully apply the search-and-replace and then re-import.

As a matter of fact I did that today :)

Comment: Glad it helps. Just make sure you apply the replacement carefully and only change what you really want.

Comment: How about the situation when I have to perform at-least 2000 replace instead of one? Could you please help?

Comment: @SachinKRaj: I'd very carefully write a shell script with 2000 `sed` statements.

Comment: this is a good method for single simple value but will probably fail in some cases of serialized array data where you also need to replace the character count of the string . ( wp has some of those in default db )

Comment: As Obmerk mentioned, this fails with SERIALIZED data. Is there any way to achieve this with serialized data? To rerun the count

Comment: Best Hack, It works and very easy.

Answer (score 23):

Came across this in a google search, but this may help some people. If you know the tables and columns (you could find this using the wildcard search in phpMyAdmin),

> UPDATE **table_name** SET **column_name** = REPLACE(**column_name**,
>   '**http://oldsite.com**','**http://newsite.com**');

Replace **bold** parts with your own.

If you had a large database you could apply this into a script that could loop through each table and column.

Comment: will `REPLACE ()` work on serialized array data as  well ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen In general, no, but it's ok if the replacement string is the same length as the one being replaced.

Answer (score 16):

The MySQL dump method would be the best bet if you're happy to re-import the whole database. For anyone that doesn't want to do this - WordPress core installation only actually consists of 11 tables, of which few are content columns, so doing a replace by column would be equally easy. Assuming you don't have loads of plugin tables referencing your link or string this would be your SQL:

```
UPDATE wp_commentmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value,'xcurrentx','xreplacementx');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = REPLACE(comment_content,'xcurrentx','xreplacementx');
UPDATE wp_links SET link_description = REPLACE(link_description,'xcurrentx','xreplacementx');
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value,'xcurrentx','xreplacementx');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value,'xcurrentx','xreplacementx');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'xcurrentx','xreplacementx');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = REPLACE(post_title,'xcurrentx','xreplacementx');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt = REPLACE(post_excerpt,'xcurrentx','xreplacementx');
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy SET description = REPLACE(description,'xcurrentx','xreplacementx');
UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value,'xcurrentx','xreplacementx');
```

Comment: This is actually better answer. I don't know why other answer is selected as correct, and having so many votes

Answer (score 3):

Your question has been posted on 2009 and during that year another guy developed a basic php tool to search for a string throughout all the tables of a certain database. Optionally you can also replace all its occurrences with a different string.

Still after 5 years (at time of writing) the use of this tool against a Wordpress installation is effective and much easier in my opinion than using a mysql dump (although you might want to create a dump as well before running the script for backup purposes).

You can find more info in the blog of its author [Eric Amundson](http://sewmyheadon.com/2009/mysql-search-replace-tool/) and in the launchpad's page of the project [MySQL Search & Replace](https://launchpad.net/mysql-search-replace)

I don't believe you are still looking for an answer after all this time, but I decided to post my hint as well, hoping it can help someone else popping over here in the future still searching for a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Addittionally to Brad Larson's answer - to set variables like:

```
SET @what_to_be_replaced = "what_to_be_replaced", @to_be_replaced_by = "to_be_replaced_by";
```

And then use it as follows:

```
UPDATE wp_commentmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, @what_to_be_replaced, @to_be_replaced_by );
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a wordpress migration recently where I had to change the domain name of the site (1012 occurrences of the site name in post data and elsewhere).
I tried the mysqldump method and used sed to replace the old with new domain names. This horribly failed after re-import, precisely because of the serialised array data present in wordpress records (my new domain name is 2 characters shorter than the old).
What worked really well, was wp-CLI, a wordpress command line interface for admin tasks. wp-cli has a built-in search-replace function for database strings that also takes care of the serialised records. It uses the credentials stored in the wp-config.php, so directly targets the wordpress database (in case your mariadb instance also hosts other databases). It's just a single php file you download and put in a folder in your path. See https://wp-cli.org/

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Wordpress plugin called [Search Regex](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/), which allows running `grep` search and replace across the database.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's REPLACE or replacing the string manually in sql file or db in **WordPress** is not a good way. WordPress uses serialized fields that may break if you replace some string in them (that was my case)

I used [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin that worked for me perfectly

Comment: unfortunately this is a no-go, if you can't even log into your site because incorrect absolute URL's are already in the database.