# postgresql - replace all instances of a string within text field

Tags: postgresql, replace

In postgresql, how do I replace all instances of a string within a database column?

Say I want to replace all instances of `cat` with `dog`, for example.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: If googling fails, try the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Comment: I think the best solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/836090/4846859

Answer (score 532, accepted):

You want to use postgresql's [replace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html) function:

```
replace(string text, from text, to text)
```

for instance :

```
UPDATE <table> SET <field> = replace(<field>, 'cat', 'dog')
```

Be aware, though, that this will be a string-to-string replacement, so 'category' will become 'dogegory'. the regexp_replace function may help you define a stricter match pattern for what you want to replace.

Comment: Hi guys, I like your answer and explanation, it is really helpful. Could you please add an example using regexp_replace? Thanks!

Comment: for better granularity, you can use `regexp_replace`

Comment: didn't work for me:
psql -d bercut -c 'UPDATE tasks_list SET link_to_report = replace(link_to_report ,"ftp://1.2.3.4/", "http://1.2.3.4/reports/")'
ERROR:  column "ftp://1.2.3.4/" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._list SET link_to_report = replace(link_to_report,"ftp://1.2...
                                                             ^

Comment: @ЕвгенийАртеменко This is probably because you used double quotes instead of quotes. Postgres is picky about that. You need single quote (i.e. '1.2.3.4' is a string, "1.2.3.4" is a _safe_ column name, a name that could be a reserved keyword).

Answer (score 112):

## The Regular Expression Way

If you need stricter replacement matching, PostgreSQL's `regexp_replace` function can match using POSIX regular expression patterns. It has the syntax ***regexp_replace(source, pattern, replacement [, flags ])***.

I will use flags `i` and `g` for case-insensitive and global matching, respectively. I will also use `\m` and `\M` to match the beginning and the end of a word, respectively.

There are usually quite a few gotchas when performing regex replacment. Let's see how easy it is to replace a *cat* with a *dog*.

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Cat bobcat cat cats catfish', 'cat', 'dog');
-->                    Cat bobdog cat cats catfish

SELECT regexp_replace('Cat bobcat cat cats catfish', 'cat', 'dog', 'i');
-->                    dog bobcat cat cats catfish

SELECT regexp_replace('Cat bobcat cat cats catfish', 'cat', 'dog', 'g');
-->                    Cat bobdog dog dogs dogfish

SELECT regexp_replace('Cat bobcat cat cats catfish', 'cat', 'dog', 'gi');
-->                    dog bobdog dog dogs dogfish

SELECT regexp_replace('Cat bobcat cat cats catfish', '\mcat', 'dog', 'gi');
-->                    dog bobcat dog dogs dogfish

SELECT regexp_replace('Cat bobcat cat cats catfish', 'cat\M', 'dog', 'gi');
-->                    dog bobdog dog cats catfish

SELECT regexp_replace('Cat bobcat cat cats catfish', '\mcat\M', 'dog', 'gi');
-->                    dog bobcat dog cats catfish

SELECT regexp_replace('Cat bobcat cat cats catfish', '\mcat(s?)\M', 'dog\1', 'gi');
-->                    dog bobcat dog dogs catfish
```

Even after all of that, there is **at least** one unresolved condition. For example, sentences that begin with "Cat" will be replaced with lower-case "dog" which break sentence capitalization.

Check out the current PostgreSQL [pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) docs for all the details.

### Update entire column with replacement text

Given my examples, maybe the safest option would be:

```
UPDATE table SET field = regexp_replace(field, '\mcat\M', 'dog', 'gi');
```

Comment: The constraints `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a **string**; but `\m` and `\M` match only at the beginning and end of a **word**. Therefore, using `^` and `$` would fail in most cases.

Answer (score 35):

You can use the `replace` function

```
UPDATE your_table SET field = REPLACE(your_field, 'cat','dog')
```

The function definition is as follows (got from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)):

```
replace(string text, from text, to text)
```

and returns the modified text. You can also check out [this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e345e).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that replaces all instances of 1 or more white space characters in a column with an underscore using regular expression -

```
select distinct on (pd)
regexp_replace(rndc.pd, '\\s+', '_','g') as pd
from rndc14_ndc_mstr rndc;
```

Comment: Only one backslash before the "s" is needed I think