# What is the best way to replace a string with another string on entire table?

Tags: postgresql, replace, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

My question is similar to below but I want to replace it for any column:

[postgresql - replace all instances of a string within text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060526/postgresql-replace-all-instances-of-a-string-within-text-field)

for instance - replace all instances of cat with dog in entire table(all rows)

I am expecting something like below query to work for all columns(without specifying the column name in update query).

```
UPDATE table_name SET information_schema.columns replace (information_schema.columns, 'old_value', 'new_value');
```

which actually doesn't seems to work.

Any suggestions please ??

Comment: Are you actually trying to change the column names themselves? Like an alter table query? Or just the content of the rows?

Comment: I don't want to change the column names. Just want to replace the content of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table sample (s varchar,s1 varchar,s2 varchar,s3 varchar,s4 varchar);

insert into sample values ('A','A','A','A','A');
insert into sample values('AB','AB','A','AB','AB');
insert into sample values('A','AB','A','AB','A');
insert into sample values('CA','A','A','CA','CA');

select * from sample
```

And try like this

```
create or replace function f1(_table text,_oldVal text,_newVal text) returns void as 
$$
declare 
rw record;
begin
for rw in 
    select 'UPDATE '||$1||' SET '||C.COLUMN_NAME||' = REPLACE ('||C.COLUMN_NAME||','''||$2||''','''||$3||'''); ' QRY
    FROM (select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='public' and table_name =$1)c
loop
    EXECUTE rw.QRY;
end loop;
end;
$$language plpgsql
```

And Call

```
select f1('sample','A','Z')

select * from sample
```

---

OR

```
do 
$$
declare 
rw record;
begin
for rw in 
    select 'UPDATE sample SET '||C.COLUMN_NAME||' = REPLACE ('||C.COLUMN_NAME||',''Z'',''A''); ' QRY
    FROM (select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='public' and table_name ='sample')c
loop
    EXECUTE rw.QRY;
end loop;
end;
$$;

select * from sample
```

Comment: Perfect !! This is what I was looking for. Thanks varchar. I can now extend this to pick the old-val, new-val pair from another table(say sample_1, which has these two columns and each value is unique). The ultimate goal is to replace all the old-value in table 'sample' by picking the new value from sample_1 table. I am thinking to get all old-new-value mapping pair as hstore and then looping it appropriately in 'Update' query. Is this fine or you have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` doesn't work that way. You need to specify each of the columns you want to change with `column = value` expressions, separated by a comma.

i.e.

```
UPDATE foo
SET bar = 1, baz = 2
WHERE bar = 5;
```

Here is more info about [`UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html), including the grammar.

Comment: Yes, this is probably a limitation in update to specify the column name. I wanted to know expert views as if there is any tricky way  to achieve it without specifying column name, which will make my task easier.

Comment: You could dynamically generate the SQL, as the other two answers have alluded to, but I'm not sure I get the use case you're looking for. You want to set *all* columns in a table to the exact same value?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to write some code. You'll need to retrieve the names of all tables and all the names that are textual:

```
select distinct table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns
    where table_schema='public'
and (data_type like 'char%' or data_type='text')
order by table_name, column_name;
```

and then **for each table/column combination**, build a query to make the replacement:

```
myQuery = "update " + table_name +
    " set " + column_name + " = replace(" + column_name +
    ", 'old_val', 'new_val')"
```

... and then execute the query in whatever language you're using. You could write this in plpgsql, but seriously, don't. This is a really dangerous piece of code.

If you're looking at doing this for a Wordpress or Drupal site, visit these guys: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: Oops, I took it to mean across all tables, not just the one table. You can change the first query above to include a "where table_name='mytable'" if you want.