# How to replace a string (data value) in whole database?

Tags: database, postgresql, replace, dynamic-sql

I want to replace a substring from all the tables say I want to replace "Center" with "Centre" in postgres. So is there any way to do this ? I found a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060526/postgresql-replace-all-instances-of-a-string-within-text-field) question to replace substring in particular column.

F.Y.I. : I am using "pgAdmin III".
I am not able to resolve my problem through solution of the similar question. I don't know any table and any column name. So I want to replace the value in entire database and in all the columns.

Comment: As answered in the very question you linked to: `update table set field = replace(field, 'cat', 'dog')`. Do that for each table (and field) as appropriate. For a wholesale change, you can also dump the data, find/replace within the .sql file, and re-import.

Comment: I tried to do so but not able to replace in whole database.

Comment: It's because you can't. You can only modify one table at a time, so need to iterate over the list of all tables, and run the query with all applicable columns for each table. Or, if you're sure you want this done wholesale, dump the data, find/replace, re-import.

Comment: I don't know all the tables and column names which have that data value so it won't be possible with given approach. It will be thankful if you can illustrate more or remove duplicate flag from the question.

Comment: @PuneetPurohit do you know which are the tables to perform this task ? and which columns ??

Comment: @PuneetPurohit see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26928214/3682599) its a kind of your problem, But in your case without knowing `column`'s name (where the `Center` is present) how can we replace the text? or you want to check `Center` in entire columns in your database ??

Comment: @PuneetPurohit As this question is marked as duplicate I cant answer here so see this http://pastie.org/9753635 Reply me if my answer worked for you

Comment: @varchar: re-opened, in case you want to expand on that pastie as an answer.

Comment: You'll have to use PL/PgSQL, queries over `information_schema` and some dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE format(...)`

Answer (score 3):

A little modification to Vivek's code:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE 
rw record;
BEGIN
FOR rw IN 
    SELECT 'UPDATE "'||C.table_name||'"  SET "'||C.column_name||'" = REPLACE ("'||C.COLUMN_NAME||'",''Center'',''Centre''); ' QRY
    FROM (SELECT column_name,table_name 
          FROM   information_schema.columns 
          WHERE  table_schema='public' 
          AND    (data_type ='text' OR data_type ='character varying')
          AND    table_name in (SELECT table_name 
                                FROM   information_schema.tables 
                                WHERE  table_schema='public' 
                                AND    table_type ='BASE TABLE'))c

LOOP
    EXECUTE rw.QRY;
END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

I added some double quotes to make it still work when table name contains underline symbol.
Works perfectly on PG 9.5.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.

Answer (score 2):

Use this select query to get all the tables and its columns(columns with data type text or character varying since you want to update a text field)

```
SELECT column_name,table_name 
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  table_schema='public' 
AND    (data_type ='text' OR data_type ='character varying') 
AND    table_name in (SELECT table_name 
                      FROM   information_schema.tables 
                      WHERE  table_schema='public' AND table_type ='BASE TABLE')
```

Wrap this in a dynamic SQL for update according to your criteria

```
DO
$$
DECLARE 
rw record;
BEGIN
FOR rw IN 
    SELECT 'UPDATE '||C.table_name||'  SET '||C.column_name||' = REPLACE ('||C.COLUMN_NAME||',''Center'',''Centre''); ' QRY
    FROM (SELECT column_name,table_name 
          FROM   information_schema.columns 
          WHERE  table_schema='public' 
          AND    (data_type ='text' OR data_type ='character varying')
          AND    table_name in (SELECT table_name 
                                FROM   information_schema.tables 
                                WHERE  table_schema='public' 
                                AND    table_type ='BASE TABLE'))c

LOOP
    EXECUTE rw.QRY;
END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: UPDATE user  SET firstname = REPLACE (firstname,'Center','Ce...
               ^
QUERY:  UPDATE user  SET firstname = REPLACE (firstname,'Center','Centre'); 
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 17 at EXECUTE statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
SQL state: 42601
Context: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 17 at EXECUTE statement

Comment: @PuneetPurohit just run `SELECT` in the for loop and comment what you're getting

Comment: I am getting all the columns from all the tables

Comment: @PuneetPurohit not that first select the SELECT inside `FOR`, btw its working in my sample `DB`

Comment: Very nice logic. Works for me beautifully with a bit of modification.

Comment: @Oxymoron88 Glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

In case you  need replace a specific word, such as "None" by NULL

```
DO
$$
DECLARE 
rw record;
BEGIN
FOR rw IN 
    SELECT 'UPDATE '||C.table_name||'  SET '||C.column_name||' = NULL where '||C.column_name||' = ''None'';' QRY
    FROM (SELECT column_name,table_name 
          FROM   information_schema.columns 
          WHERE  table_schema='public' 
          AND    (data_type ='text' OR data_type ='character varying')
          AND    table_name = 'rdb_deal')c
LOOP
    EXECUTE rw.QRY;
END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```