# Accessing postgres data structure

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in my postgres table which has data structured strangely. Here is an example of the data structure:

```
id         |        1
name       |        name
data       |        :type: information
           |        :url: url
           |        :platform: 
           |          android: ''
           |          iphone: ''
created_at |        2016-07-29 11:39:44.938359
updated_at |        2016-08-22 12:24:32.734321
```

How do i change data > platform > android for example?

Comment: Your notation is rather mysterious, what is the type of `data`?

Comment: Sorry. Data type is `text`. Its a strange data structure. I don't think if I have to update a single value e.g. android I would have to output the whole data contents again including the new value ie `update table set data = ':type: information :url: url :platform: android: 'new_value' iphone: ''` I know this isnt the correct way but you get my point. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, Postgres has no built-in means to update parts of text, so you have to format whole new value manually (or in your application).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Seems to be bad database design. Will be chatting to my colleagues tomorrow and add any further information I might get. Thanks.

Comment: Just realised I can run replace. Mightnt have been obvious as the data for android was empty but can run `update table set field = replace(field, 'android: ''''', 'android: ''new_value''')`. Does that seem okay to you?

Answer (score 0):

Just did some more research and found this which did the trick:

[postgresql - replace all instances of a string within text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060526/postgresql-replace-all-instances-of-a-string-within-text-field)