# upate statement using replace in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.2

I have table having below records

```
Sno  A
-    --
1   spoo74399p 
2   spoo75399p
```

I want to update the above records by replacing `oo` (alphabet 'o') by zero

```
Required OUTPUT
----------------
Sno     A

1   sp0074399p 
2   sp0075399p
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060526/postgresql-replace-all-instances-of-a-string-within-text-field

Comment: Does this answer your question? [postgresql - replace all instances of a string within text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060526/postgresql-replace-all-instances-of-a-string-within-text-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here to be as specific as possible:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET A = REGEXP_REPLACE(A, '^spoo', 'sp00');
```

This would only target the `oo` occurring near the beginning, after `sp`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to update the above records by replacing oo (alphabet 'o') by zero

Is this what you are looking for?

```
update mytable set a = replace(a, 'oo', '00')
```