# MySql, Wordpress, REPLACE part of post_content text using LIKE (REGEX) operator..

Tags: mysql, regex, select, sql-like

Posts in wordpress have unwanted links in post_content, like

```
http://www.thisisbaddomain.com/?x=blahblah (or similar to first blank)
```

http://thisisbaddomain.com/?x=blahblah
www.thisisbaddomain.com/?x=blahblah

I heed solution...php code which will replace all those links from start to first blank (or remove whole line if link is alone on that line)..

I do testing without success with:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, regex '^(http://www.xxx.com)', '');
```

I know that this example do not work and I understand that regex do not work like LIKE in sql..and I am stuck...I know that someone have problem like this before..so please give me something to work with I will change it to suit me..

Answer (score 1):

I think you possible want something likes this :

[How to search and replace all instances of a string within a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836083/how-to-search-and-replace-all-instances-of-a-string-within-a-database)

or maybe this

[Search for all occurrences of a string in a mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562457/search-for-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL 8 you can use REGEXP_REPLACE

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '^(http://www.example.com)', '')
```