# How to change shipping to delivery in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

I installed `prestashop` to my e-commerce website which is to sell product to local people only.
So I need to change all the `'Shipping'` word instances to `'Delivery'`.

I have changed translations to change this.But still some places displays word 'shipping' 
rather than 'delivery'.

So what is the easiest way to change all 'shipping 'occurrences to 'delivery'

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that other "Shipping" occurrences that you find are probably located in the database (fields that you can fill in using the admin panel), therefore you will have to look into it as well. Normally it should not be too many of those so you can try and find them via the PrestaShop admin panel (notably in order statuses for "shipping"). But if you want to make sure you can use a global database replace method such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/836090/1439597), but be careful not to replace any field name! Only values.

Comment: Thanks dude.I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have not checked for "Shipping" in both "Front Office" and "Modules" part of the "Translations". If you post URL I can tell you if this is part of the templates or from the database.