# replace a word in all wordpress posts and pages, title,excerpt and content

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am new to mysql and phpmyadmin so excuse my question if it's basic.
I need a query to replace the 15$ to 10$ on all posts and pages post_title, post_excerpt and post_content using the insert method not update method.
also is there any way to undo the query if things went wrong ?

Comment: Is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74137932/combine-3-queries-in-one-query-to-replace-all-strings-15-with-10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = REPLACE WHERE post_type = 'post',post_type = 'page' (post_title, '$15', '10$'), post_content = REPLACE WHERE post_type = 'post',post_type = 'page'(post_content, '$15', '$10'), post_excerpt = REPLACE WHERE post_type = 'post',post_type = 'page'(post_excerpt, '$15', '$10');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should back up your database first from `PHPMyAdmin` -> `Export`.

You can't `REPLACE` without UPDATE.

As a second solution, after backup, if your MySQL dump is small enough, you could edit the SQL file with Notepad++, replace 15$ with 10$ and import everything in a new database and switch DB connections. This would meet the requirement: of using only the `INSERT` method.

Comment: I need to updated all at once post_title, post_content and post_excerpt in single posts and pages all in one query to avoid several updates for posts and pages as it will cause many google indexing.
so I eneded up here but I need it all to be combined in one query, what do you think ?
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, '15$', '10$');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = replace(post_title, '15$', '10$');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_excerpt, '15$', '10$');

Comment: Yes, the UPDATE with REPLACE it's the fastest method, but like I mentioned, please backup your database first. You don't have to worry about google indexing, googlebot will re-crawl important pages at least every few days, and even more frequently in some cases: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/googles-john-mueller-reveals-often-site-re-indexed-search/241427/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your database looks like without an example and I'm not sure why you want to avoid the update method but maybe
[this](https://database.guide/mysql-replace-all-instances-of-a-substring-with-another-string/) will help you with your question.

This does use the update function however but I don't see a way around it other than exporting your database to an sql file, updating the rows through either a script or search and replace in a text editor.

My solution would be to use your text editor or use a query like

```sql
UPDATE posts SET post_title = REPLACE(post_title,'$15','$10');
```

You might also want to take a look at this: [How to search and replace all instances of a string within a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836083/how-to-search-and-replace-all-instances-of-a-string-within-a-database)

Comment: I am not sure why our head of development was shocked that I used the update method and insisted that we have to use the insert method ;/ she didn't answer any further questions.

Comment: so I eneded up here but I need it all to be combined in one query, what do you think ?
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, '15$', '10$');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = replace(post_title, '15$', '10$');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_excerpt, '15$', '10$');

Comment: I don't know how your senior developer (I'm assuming) is expecting to run this process through. I don't know if you're operating with a live database nor how large it is but I would personally suggest shutting it down for maintenance, (carefully) text editing the sql file, upload it back and leave it at that. It could be smart to have a test database for this while you're at it.

Comment: Otherwise if you really need to make it into one query you'll have to write it all out by hand with the previously mentioned query: `UPDATE table SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, 'oldstring', 'newstring') WHERE column_name LIKE '%oldstring%'`

Comment: **EDIT**: `UPDATE table SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, 'oldstring', 'newstring'), column_name2 = REPLACE(column_name2, 'oldstring2', 'newstring2')` You could also try adding `WHERE column_name LIKE '%oldstring%'` which may or may not optimize the query

Comment: it's huge database that's why i wont be able to update file.

UPDATE table SET post_title = REPLACE(post_title, '15$', '10$'), post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '15$', '10$'), post_excerpt = REPLACE(post_excerpt, '15$', '10$')

Answer (score 0):

let me introduce my solution :
**replace specific string in posts**

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = REPLACE(post_title, '$15', '$10'), post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '$15', '$10'), post_excerpt = REPLACE(post_excerpt, '$15', '$10') WHERE post_type = 'post';

**but I would recommend using the first answer for more covering**

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = REPLACE WHERE post_type = 'post',post_type = 'page' (post_title, '$15', '10$'), post_content = REPLACE WHERE post_type = 'post',post_type = 'page'(post_content, '$15', '$10'), post_excerpt = REPLACE WHERE post_type = 'post',post_type = 'page'(post_excerpt, '$15', '$10');
```

**replace specific string in pages**

```
UPDATE postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, '$15', '$10');
```

**change on wp yoast SEO plugin values meta_titles and meta_description**

```
UPDATE wp_yoast_indexable SET title = REPLACE(title, '$15', '$10'), description = REPLACE(description, '$15', '$10');
```