# Combine 3 queries in one query to replace all strings "15$" with 10$"

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, sql-insert

In wp_posts table I need to replace a the string "15$" with "10$" in pages and posts post_title, posts_content , post_excerpt, I have a request to use use insert not update and to have only 1 query to do it all for posts and pages and of course only the price will change the rest of content will remain the same.

````
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, '15$', '10$');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = replace(post_title, '15$', '10$');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt = replace(post_excerpt, '15$', '10$');```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You've tagged this with phpMyAdmin, which has a handy search and replace feature, but I'm confused by your requirements to do this in an insert rather than update and in a single query. What are the purposes of those requirements? What should happen to the old data if you're not updating existing rows?

Answer (score 0):

let me inroduce my final solution:
in case of wordpress database we need to update posts, pages , ACF and seo yost plugin values

**update title, description and excerpt in both posts and pages :**

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = REPLACE WHERE post_type = 'post',post_type = 'page' (post_title, '$15', '10$'), post_content = REPLACE WHERE post_type = 'post',post_type = 'page'(post_content, '$15', '$10'), post_excerpt = REPLACE WHERE post_type = 'post',post_type = 'page'(post_excerpt, '$15', '$10');
```

**replace specific string in pages postmeta where we have ACF:**

```
UPDATE postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, '$15', '$10');
```

**change on yoast values:**

```
UPDATE wp_yoast_indexable SET title = REPLACE(title, '$15', '$10'), description = REPLACE(description, '$15', '$10');
```